# Is it possible for angular lib to use nested public_api.ts

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

A very big library I am creating, so naturally I am thinking to modularise the `public_api.ts` for different huge modules.

But it seems I cannot achieve that via something like this in the root `public_api.ts`:

```
export * from "./lib/lib2-m1/public_api";
export * from "./lib/lib2-m2/public_api";
```

And also the `ng-package.json` used by *ng-packagr* is using `entryFile` which is a **singular**.

A simple [demo](https://github.com/Hearen/smallest-demos/tree/master/lib-with-nested-public_api) to present the case.

Any idea will be appreciated for better modularisation of the *big* lib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try creating `index.ts` file with `public-api.ts` file and use that index file in root public-api.ts file in root `public-api.ts`

```js
export * from "./lib/lib2-m1/index";
export * from "./lib/lib2-m2/index";
```

This worked in my project.

Comment: and what if I'd like to have one library but group it inside so then I can do: `import { SomeService } from '@myOrg/lib/services';` and `import { SomeEntity } from '@myOrg/lib/model';`

Comment: you can do it by using both public-api.ts and index.ts together, ex:- export all services from public-api.ts and then export public-api.ts in index.ts file

Comment: Interesting idea! Just not sure if I understood - considering `public-api.ts` already flattens all the exports - how `index.ts` can provide a subset and how it can be nested / grouped into “sub-modules”?

Comment: the nested/grouped structure is provided by public-api.ts(whatever you export inside this file you can import from the library providing correct path), and the index.ts just make importing syntax easier like `@myOrg/lib/services`